# How to alias a Material-UI import?

Tags: reactjs

I want to import Button as MaterialButton alias

```js
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
const test => (<Button></Button>)
```

to

```js
import * as MaterialButton from "@material-ui/core/Button";
const test => (<MaterialButton></MaterialButton>)
```

I get this error
[image]

---

I just found out that this also works in addition to Viet's answer

```js
import {Button as MaterialButton} from "@material-ui/core";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just rename import like this:

```
import MaterialButton from "@material-ui/core/Button";
```

Comment: This is shall not be an answer, as he asks to use a wildcard `*` instead of default import

Comment: He want to rename component. Not to use a wildcard

Comment: This answer is good enough to answer the question of renaming an import. Could you explain how the computer knows to import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button" when I can give it any name?